# Is MD5 hash a bijection for input length < $2^{128}$ bits

Tags: probability, hash-function

The [MD5 hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#MD5_hashes) have a length of 128 bits. It seems therefore obvious that if we could get all hashes from MD5 for more than $2^{128}$ inputs, at least 2 hashes would be identical.

But what if we could provide all $2^{128}$ possible inputs to MD5, would we get distinct hashes?
In other words is MD5 a bijection if input has always less than $2^{128}$ bits?

Comment: MD5 Hash function is built so, that it can imitate pseudo-random number generating. Definitely, it must have many collisions in the first $2^{128}$ samples. MD5 isn't bijection. Distribution of MD5 values is very close to uniformly distributed random value with values $0,1,...,2^{128}-1$.

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack . Especially Table, where you can find, that if one will choose $\approx 2^{64}$ random samples, then probability of collision is $\approx 0.5$. If one will choose $\approx 2^{65}$ samples, then probability of collision is $> 0.75$.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question.

Comment: I'm afraid the argument presented by @Oleg567 only expresses our *expectations* about the hash function, rather than a *proof* that they are valid (although I *do* believe his conclusions). As an example, the (non-cryptographic) CRC32 hash is quite nice when it comes to the distribution of its values too but at the same time, it has no collisions on $32$-bit inputs.

Comment: Thanks again. You guys must have too much rep, as these comments would have made great answers!